# Fuga de memória em Player de vídeo

Tags: c++, winforms, memória

Estou a implementar uma aplicação em C++/cli e WinForms que apresenta vídeos de forma contínua. Durante a execução, quando os vídeos são carregados a memória aumenta e é libertada depois. Reparei que ao fim de algum tempo, a memória utilizada vai subindo. Ao fim de um dia inteiro de execução a aplicação é terminada por haver esta fuga de memória.

Já isolei o player dos restantes componentes para verificar se de facto era aí que residia o problema. Já experimentei alguns players - MediaPlayer component, ActiveX VLC, VideoLANDotNet ou DirectX SDK - mas o problema mantem-se, por vezes de forma não tão evidente mas acaba sempre por acontecer.

Alguem teve um problema parecido ? É necessário parar ou iniciar algum serviço para que o sistema operativo permita estas operações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem basicamente duas razões para o espaço de endereçamento ir apenas aumentando: vazamento de memória e fragmentação de memória.

No vazamento não muito o que fazer além de executar ferramentas como `cppcheck` e `valgrind` a fim de que elas identifiquem os vazamentos.

O `cppcheck` irá fazer a análise estática do código fonte, e identificará erros como más práticas de programação, variáveis alocadas que saem do escopo sem ser desalocadas, etc. Porém, ela não é muito precisa uma vez que realiza apenas análise estática, mas tem a vantagem de ser mais rápida.

Já o `valgrind` irá analisar todas as alocações de memória, realizando o profiling da aplicação a fundo, e irá apontar toda memória vazada na aplicação.

Caso elas identifiquem algum erro, elas irão te dar informações que te ajudarão a resolver o problema (embora nem sempre elas sejam claras).

Já no caso da fragmentação de memória, o que acontece é o seguinte: a memória não é alocada em pedaços pequenos (seja pelo SO ou pelo runtime sendo utilizado), e sim em páginas de memória (geralmente com pelo menos 4KB), e então divida em pedaços menores.

Porém, se há uma página com apenas 4 bytes ocupados, e se deseja ocupar outros 4KB, não é possível aproveitar a página que esta praticamente livre, e sim realizar a alocação de uma nova página. Note que formou um "buraco" em uma das páginas que não foi utilizado, mas que neste caso é grande o suficiente para ser utilizado novamente em uma alocação no decorrer do programa.

Em alguns casos, no entanto, o "buraco" é pequeno demais e acaba sendo impossível alocá-lo para algum uso útil. Claro que isto depende de como o programa foi desenvolvido, se ele costuma desalocar grandes pedaços de memória, ou se a memória é alocada indefinidamente, dentre outros fatores. Mas o importante, é que isto pode causar que o programa aloque cada vez mais memória, embora não esteja exatamente vazando, e sim apenas fragmentando.

Um modo de evitar estes problemas é alocar o maior número de variáveis possível na pilha. Assim, quando elas saem de escopo, elas são automaticamente liberadas, evitando memory leak. Além disso, a pilha é uma região com endereços sempre contíguos e alocados em sequência, e portanto não ocorre fragmentação de memória, além de possuir acesso mais rápido do a heap.

Alguns componentes apenas desalocam memória quando o componente inteiro é desalocado, Ou seja, imagine que você criou o player e esta tocando videos nele. Porém, ele não foi tão bem escrito assim, e ele acaba conservando alguns (ou vários) bytes entre um video e outro ao invés de liberá-los. Porém, os programadores tomaram cuidado de liberar a memória quando o componente é destruído. Uma opção seria então ao final de cada video recriar o componente (ou a cada 2 videos, depende das suas necessidades). Por incrível que pareça, já vi isto ocorrer.

Enfim, a solução ideal é encontrar o vazamento e corrigi-lo. Além do mais, se em todos estes componentes o vazamento ocorre, analize se ele não esta ocorrendo no seu código ao invés do código dos outros. Pode ser que o erro seja muito sútil, mas que com ferramentas como o `valgrind` o erro pode ser identificado.

Espero ter ajudado em algo, e desculpe pelo longo texto.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção e resposta!